# HTML Comments Throwing Off Sizing

Tags: css, comments, html

UPDATE: The problem as been solved. I've answered below with my solution, but cannot accept until alloted time has passed.

I have an html comment like below

```
<!-- comment
    comment
   comment
-->
```

With the comment in  my webpage, the formatting of everything is off. Without it, the formatting is fine. Has anyone run into comments causing issues with CSS or HTML before, or is this most likely another portion of my code causing the real issue?

Comment: That is very much dependent on the editor you use and it's formatting rules.

Comment: more details please! what's 'formatting'? give more context code, supply environment info (tested browsers, libraries etc.)

Comment: @svenbieer The editor? I was under the impression that this would be a browser interpreter issue. The editor is just a way to change the code in my head. I could use notepad for that. Perhaps you mean something different by editor?

Comment: @EliranMalka Apologies. On second look, this is highly sparse. I would add more information, but I just found the solution as I posted this.

Comment: FYI, `<input type="hidden" />` occupies space strangely enough.  Don't ask me why.

Comment: @Neil Yeah, that is odd. I guess you'd have to display:none to have any element not take up space.

Comment: @steventnorris, yes, that works.  Took me a full day of hair pulling before someone told me that hidden inputs weren't so hidden afterall.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The comments were outside the html tag, which can cause formatting oddities (tested in IE7). It is good practice to include comments within HTML tags. I've now placed the comments within the head tag and it solved the issue.

Comment: Comments *do not* cause "huge formatting difficulties". IE6 does have some bugs concerning comments, and maybe some other browsers in edge cases, but you can't say that so generally. What browser do you see it in? Is your document in Standards mode? Post some real-life exmaples (URLs)!

Comment: @RoToRa I am using IE7 for testing, but can't post a URL due to the fact that the site is a local intranet site. I'll edit the answer to change the sweeping nature.

Comment: You can used services such as jsfiddle to post examples.

Comment: @RoToRa If you put anything at all (including comments or an XML prolog) before the HTML DOCTYPE, IE6, 7, 8 and 9 are thrown into Quirks mode. In this particular case, HTML comments can and will cause huge formatting difficulties :)

Comment: @Olly: I consider that one of the IE6 bugs I mentioned :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this behavior once before, but then I realized that it wasn't the comments causing formatting problems but the whitespaces I create when I add the comment.  In other words, if you want a guaranteed way that comments won't affect formatting, you must put it next to another object on the same line with no spaces in between.

Good:

```
  <!--  This is a comment
        with multiple lines --><span>HTML code</span>
```

Bad:

```
  <!--  This is a comment
        with multiple lines -->
  <span>HTML code</span>
```

Then, you might decide that it doesn't bother you that much afterall, since reading bunched up html code is a programmer's hell.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't noticed this yet, but now I'm going to go back and check all of my spacing comments for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: @steventnorris, you should know that it depends on the browser you're using and where the comment has been made also.